# CSS padding not applying to parent div

Tags: html, css

I really don't understand CSS :(

Why is the following `padding` not pushing out the size of the parent div?

**HTML**

```
 <div class="lead-table">
        <div class="row table-head-1">
            <div class="col-md-9"> 
              <span><strong>My Leads</strong></span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**CSS**

```
 .lead-table .table-head-1 {
        background-color: #053449;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        color: #ffffff;
        font-size: 12px;
    }
    .lead-table .table-head-1 span {
        padding: 20px 18px;
    }
```

http://www.bootply.com/gsT2mwsA8h#

Any help appreciated for this CSS noob.

Thanks

Comment: Span is non block element. Did you tried .lead-table .table-head-1 span {
    padding: 20px 18px; display: inline-block;
}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unlike `div`, `p` <sup>1</sup> which are [Block Level](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#block-boxes) elements which can take up `padding` or `margin` on all sides,`span`<sup>2</sup> cannot as it's an [Inline](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#inline-boxes) element which takes up `padding` or `margin` horizontally only.

From the [specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html#padding-properties) :

Use `div` instead of `span`...below code will work

```
.lead-table .table-head-1 {
    background-color: #053449;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 12px;
}
.lead-table .table-head-1 .col-txt{
    padding: 20px 18px;
}


<div class="lead-table">
    <div class="row table-head-1">
        <div class="col-md-9"> 
          <div class='col-txt'><strong>My Leads</strong></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

`span` is not a block element.

`padding` will not work for inline elements. But `margin` will work.

- either you can use `margin: 20px 18px;`  or
- add `display:block;` or `display:inline-block;` to the span.

`padding` will take effect once you make it a block element.

Answer (score 0):

Just replace that both css with following, it may help you :-

```
.lead-table .table-head-1 {
    background-color: #053449;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 12px;
    padding: 20px 18px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your html needs to be wrapped in a "container" class division tag with bootstrap.

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
 <div class="lead-table">
    <div class="row table-head-1">
        <div class="col-md-9"> 
          <span><strong>My Leads</strong></span>
        </div>
    </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Also, your CSS can be reduced for what you have currently as shown below.

CSS:

```
/* CSS used here will be applied after bootstrap.css */
.lead-table{
    background-color: #053449;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 12px;
}
.table-head-1{
    padding: 20px 18px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By default a span is an inline element. You cannot add padding top or bottom to it unless you add `display:block`.

```
.lead-table .table-head-1 span {
    padding: 20px 18px;
    display:block;
}
```

Working code example: http://www.bootply.com/kSh1hNCkTb#